# Updating Credential on Alamofire AuthenticationInterceptor in Singleton (Alamofire 5 / Swift 5)

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, oauth, alamofire

I have a singleton API manager class as below to create a shared 'authenticated' Alamofire session for my application.

```
class APIManager {

    static let shared = APIManager()
    
    let sessionManager: Session = {
        
        //Applies authentication interceptor to all API calls
        let authenticator = APIOAuthAuthenticator()
        let interceptor = AuthenticationInterceptor(authenticator: authenticator,
                                                    credential: TokenManager.shared.loadTokens())
        
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.af.default

        return Session(configuration: configuration, interceptor: interceptor)
    }()
```

This loads the initial credential from a TokenManager class.

Alamofire does the heavy lifting for me in terms of refreshing the tokens when necessary, however, there's an edge case where the credentials are nil on instantiation - giving the 'missing credentials' error from Alamofire.

In this case, when I login, get new credentials, which are then accessible through TokenManager, however since the singleton session is already instantiated, I see no way to directly update this credentials to the new credentials.

**Is this a fundamental problem with my pattern or is there some way to have credential merely be a pointer to something dynamic elsewhere that I can update?**

Apologies for any poor use of terminology, a relative newcomer to swift and a complete newcomer to Alamofire.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, however, someone with the same problem may still end up here so I will answer it.

Your pattern is reasonable, but needs to be adjusted so that the credentials can be updated. You need to store a reference to the `AuthenticationInterceptor` so that its public property `credential` can be updated. The easiest way to do so is to ditch the closure to instantiate `sessionManager` and do something like this:

```swift
class APIManager {
    static let shared = APIManager()
    let sessionManager: Session
    private let interceptor: AuthenticationInterceptor<APIOAuthAuthenticator>

    private init() {
        let authenticator = APIOAuthAuthenticator()
        // store the reference to interceptor so that the credential property can be updated when neccessary
        interceptor = AuthenticationInterceptor(authenticator: authenticator,
                                                credential: TokenManager.shared.loadTokens())
        sessionManager = Session(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.af.default, interceptor: interceptor)
    }
    
    func reloadCredentialFromTokenManager() {
        interceptor.credential = TokenManager.shared.loadTokens()
    }
}
```

Finally, after saving your new credential details in your `TokenManager` simply call

```swift
APIManager.shared.reloadCredentialFromTokenManager()
```

Hope this helps!